UIKit prompt give me an error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded."
I have this problem, it seems like it's a problem with my html since I'm using a UIKit modal and I'm calling another modal within the first one, it seems like this is a problem.
I don't know if there is a way to resolve this, or is there any other way to get around this situation?
In my modal there is a button, when I click it it opens a prompt where I was supposed to write something, but an error appears in the Console and I can't type anything, but the buttons work correctly.
I use: "uikit": "^3.21.5"
And my angular is in version 16.2.0
The Error:
uikit.js:2874 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (uikit.js:2874:21)
    at M.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at N.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at j.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:483:34)
    at J (zone.js:1631:18)
    at ue (zone.js:1674:33)
    at HTMLDocument.Ae (zone.js:1695:16)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (uikit.min.js:2490:52)
    at M.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at N.runTask (zone.js:173:47)

My Component:
    @Component({
  selector: 'show-card-modal',
  templateUrl: './show-card.modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show-card.modal.component.css'],
})
export class ShowCardModalComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  public comments: boolean = false;

  @Input() public title: string = '';
  @Input() public description: string = '';
  @Input() public imagePortrait: string = '';
  @Input() public city: string = '';
  @Input() public address: string = '';
  @Input() public cep: string = '';
  @Input() public number: string = '';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('comments' in changes) {
      this.comments = changes['comments'].currentValue;
    }
  }

  comment(){
        UIkit.modal.prompt('Name:', 'Your name').then((name: any) => {
      console.log('Prompted:', name);
    });
  }
}

My HTML:
<div id="modal-full" class="uk-modal-full" style="background-color:#f5f5f5" uk-modal>
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-full uk-close-large" type="button" uk-close></button>

    <div class="uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-1-2@s" uk-grid>
      <div
        class="uk-background-cover"
        style="background-image: url({{ imagePortrait }});"
        uk-height-viewport
      ></div>
      <div class="uk-padding-large">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ description }}</p>
        <p>{{ city }}</p>
        
        <div class="button-57" role="button" (click)="comment()"><span class="text">Coment</span><span>Second interation!</span></div>

        <div class="comments-container" *ngIf="true">
          <ul class="uk-comment-list">
            <li>
              <article
                class="uk-comment uk-visible-toggle"
                tabindex="-1"
                role="comment"
              >
                <header class="uk-comment-header uk-position-relative">
                  <div class="uk-grid-medium uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
                    <div class="uk-width-expand">
                      <h4 class="uk-comment-title uk-margin-remove">
                        <a class="uk-link-reset" href="#">Author</a>
                      </h4>
                      <p class="uk-comment-meta uk-margin-remove-top">
                        <a class="uk-link-reset" href="#">12 days ago</a>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    class="uk-position-top-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover"
                  >
                    <a class="uk-link-muted" href="#">Reply</a>
                  </div>
                </header>
                <div class="uk-comment-body">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
                    diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
                    justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
                    sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

